# Microsoft Interop OutLook C#- Cannot save attachments of type OLE

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, office-interop, com-interop

I have a C# program saving attachments from unread emails from Outlook mail box to a folder and the below line of code breaks(first line) for attachment types that are of OLE type with the error "Outlook cannot perform this action on this type of attachment"(Where 'it' is of type `MailItem`).

```
string attachedfilename = it.Attachments[i].FileName;
it.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile("C:\\temp\\"+attachedfilename);
```

I have read articles on using http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm (library) to overcome this problem for Ole type attachments, but apart from this option can I make use of any other .NET Library to overcome this problem?
If yes, kindly share the code snippet in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to call `IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ, IID_IStorage, ...)` then open a particular stream from `IStorage` that contains the data that you are after. Note that the stream and its format are specific to the application that created the OLE attachment. `IAttach::OpenProperty` is only available in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you cannot do that in C#. [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) supports Word Pad, Paint Brush, Excel, Power Point, Word, Open Office, Acrobat, bitmap, metafile, etc. formats when you call `RDOAttachment.SaveAsFile`.

To see the data stored in Outlook, take a look at the attachment with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am also its author): select the message, click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on the attachment, right click on the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property, select `IMAPIProp::OpenProperty`, select `IStorage` interface.

Comment: I decided to go with Redemption since it is a managed code. I followed the steps mentioned in the redemption tutorials to get the attachments. However the MAPIOBJECT seems to be deprecated in the latest Outlook API and i cannot get this to work. Can you help?  Sample Code ->  Application appobj = new Application(); 
RDOSession RDSObj = new RDOSession();
RDSObj.MAPIOBJECT = appobj.Session.MAPIOBJECT; //MAPIOBJECT not showing up in intellisense
var MailObj = RDSObj.GetMessageFromID(it.EntryID);

foreach(Attachment att in RDSObj.Attachments)
{
  att.SaveAsFile("foldername");
}

Comment: Namespace.MAPIOBJECT is not deprecated: it returns IMAPISession Extended MAPI object, but since it is useless in VBA or ..Net languages, the type library marks it as hidden. If you don't want to reuse the existing Outlook session, you can call RDOSession.Logon instead.

Comment: I would prefer to re-use the existing outlook session. I have the Application and Namespace objects that i had created from Interop Outlook. Can you provide the line of code that i need to assign RDSObj.MAPIOBJECT with or sample code in C#?

Comment: RDSObj.MAPIOBJECT = appobj.Session.MAPIOBJECT; would work - even though Intelllisense does not show Namespace.MAPIOJECT, you can still use it in your code.

Comment: Perfect!! This works after some back and forth and referring your articles in social MSDN. Finally i got this to work :) One last last query ->The olOle Image that i got from the attachment is placed with name "Picture Device Independent Bitmap.bmp"  and is not having a proper name. Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: There is no other display name set on the attachment, but you can name the file any way your want when you call SaveAsFile.

Comment: IAttach::OpenProperty is only available in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you cannot do that in C#. - That is not true. It can be implemented in C# as well.

Comment: Sure, if you convert the Extended MAPI headers to C#. There used to be MAPI33 library, but it is no longer being developed or supported.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual argument passed to the SaveAsFile method of the Attachment class?

Note, the C: requires admin privileges for writing, I'd suggest choosing another drive or folder (in a user profile).

As a workaroud you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook and Redemption are based on - Extended MAPI. You will need to open the PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ property using the IAttach::OpenProperty property and open the stream as IMessage.

Comment: The exception is thrown in the first line "string attachedfilename = it.Attachments[i].FileName;" for ole types. For regular mail attachments , those two lines of code work perfectly(I have write access to the C:\Temp folder). Can you share code or link on using the Extended MAPI with C#? Any way i can pass the MailItem.EntryId to this API to grab the OLE attachments and save them to a folder.

Comment: See [Opening an Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842411.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).